# PHP webservice require file error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a webservice with PHP and MySQL but I get errors when I try to require files. Here's my code:

db_config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "a1605031_test2");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "******");
define('DB_DATABASE', "a1605031_test2");
define('DB_SERVER', "mysql13.000webhost.com");
?>
```

DB_CONNECT.php

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        return $con;
    }

    function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

?>
```

But when I open test.php I get this

```
require_once() [function.require]:
 Failed opening required '__DIR__/db_connect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
 in /home/a1605031/public_html/test2/test.php on line 2
```

So how should I require the file ? I'm using 000webhost.com, if it matters.

Comment: Why are you investing so much time in using the creaky, antiquated `mysql_query` interface? It looks like you're slowly building your own framework here.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP is installed? It looks like `__DIR__` isn't defined - which was added in PHP 5.3. Try this instead:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/db_connect.php';
```

Comment: It seems its 5.2, I tried your code but I still get the same error